# WPF Treeview (MVVM) realtime represention (grouping) of binding source

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, wpf-controls, reactiveui

Can anyone offer any pointers or examples of a WPF treeview (bound to a realtime source) where each root node and its children represents a different kind of summary of the binding source?

*Apology - I don't normally ask such open 'write some example code' questions like this but i'm relatively new to WPF and struggling to get a foothold on the best way forward.*

For example;

```
Year of Birth
 [] 80 (2)
 [] 85 (1)
 [] 90 (14)

Course
 [] Engineering (20)
 [] Accountancy (2)

Gender
 [] Male (10)
 [] Female (1)
```

This treeview for example would have been bound against an observable list of students (the student model would contain their DOB, Course studied and gender). The [] signifies a checkbox that would allow the user to filter the datasource based on their selection.

ps. I will be using the MVVM approach and planning on using ReactiveUI.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the basics - actually representing this view:

```
IEnumerable<ICategoryTileViewModel> TreeView;

public interface ICategoryTileViewModel
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IFilterValueTileViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public interface IFilterValueTileViewModel
{
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CurrentCount { get; set; }
}
```

How you generate the TreeView depends on what your data source looks like, which you haven't mentioned yet. However, it almost certainly involves the `GroupBy` operator

Answer (score 0):

This involves modifying the item template of tree view by using a HierarchicalDataTemplate which should look something like this:

Your View

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="{Binding Description}">
                <!--You can add your checkbox here and remove the image-->
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Height="16" Width="16"/>
                <!--You can add your checkbox here and remove the image-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="4,0,4,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Your VM should inherit from this class

```
public abstract class VM
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public ObservableCollection<VM> Children {get; set;}
}
```

The data context of your application should expose Children which points to the item source of the tree view.

You will have to extend this to your idea of summary for a tree view.